# Texture becomes black when tryng to bake vertex color to texture!

Tags: texture-baking, baking, vertex-colors

when I UV smart project my model, then open a new file (thats black) where I want my vertex color to bake to. The texture only becomes black. It doesnt make any sense.
Please look at attached file:
https://gyazo.com/045b606b616df5907c79aaf2cf10d7e0

I have multiple guns that I would like to bake a texture from. So please post an explanation when you fix the gun. Thanks!

Here is the gun (Glock 18):
[image]

EDIT:
Hey, I used the answer that Craig wrote. Basically, I got the colors etc. But the texture was very "round" compared to Craigs. 
I do not know why.

What I did:
(Firstly changed from Cycles to Blender Render)

1. Make the whole model "one", so I can edit the whole thing at once.(CTRL + J)
2. Smart UV Project the whole thing.
3. Add blank, black image.
4. Go to bake, choose Textures. And Bake the whole thing.

WHAT I GOT: (Please see attached link)
https://gyazo.com/be11838d12f9b26fc78943d09faec235

> When I used the texture on a Model in ROBLOX STUDIO the model just went black.
>   (See link)
>   https://gyazo.com/9f3838c2061a552da4361bbf32b881f1

Why??
What have I done wrong?
Why does it look so different from yours? (I know I did something wrong!)
Please tell me. It would mean the world to me! Seriously, I got to get the game out in February! Thanks!

Comment: Are your normals inverted or are they correctly pointing outward? Have you tried a recent build on builder.blender.org to see if maybe something is updated now compared to your build?

Comment: Welcome, Felix. Use this link to upload a .blend file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @LeoNas, hey I uploaded it to the blender thing... It is now in my question!

Comment: @CraigDJones Hey, sorry for the late response. I am pretty new to blender, so could you clarify what you mean.

Comment: @CraigDJones, hey I had some questions on your answer :) I would appreciate it if you would answer

Comment: @CraigDJones Hey just edited the question! Please read! Thanks!

Comment: @CraigDJones, I hope I am not strenuous, but it would really help me :)

Comment: Your margin is set at 16 pixels, maybe you are seeing too much color and calling that rounding? Try set to less like 10 or so.

Comment: Did you save the image texture after baking so that the pixel colors are permanent? Black is the default generated image color.

Comment: I will come back to you later today! Thanks for the response, really means a lot to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no vertex colors, your file has blender render materials but is set to Cycles right now. Turn it back to Blender render. In your scene, you have no light source, so every bake will be black.

edit: My steps were incorrect the first time, so here is a corrected flow:
1. Your file as it is with Cycles as renderer but has no Node materials.
[image]
2. I switch to Blender Render and find your UV are wrong, so I Smart UV Unwrap
[image]
3.I also then remember in Blender Render that I can bake using Textures to get the straight diffuse color without a lamp
[image]
And then the result comes out pretty clean
[image]

Comment: So all I need to do is: Set it to Blender Render and insert a light source. Am I right?

Comment: If I add a lamp, wouldn´t my texture get a shadow or not?

Comment: is that right? And, what should I use, a Light or?

Comment: BTW, I recalculated the normals (in the whole model), but nothing seemed to be fixed. Just the old same, thing. Could you maybe write what I need too do or redirect me to a tutorial? Thanks

Comment: See my edits above.

Comment: Hey Craig, please see my edit. It didn't quite work :( I feel like an idiot right now...

Comment: Hey just edite dmy question, would mean alot if you read it!!

Comment: Hi Craig, not sure if you saw my edit??

Comment: Hey, the issue was with the game engine I believe. Thanks for the help!